# How do I disable SSL on a GoDaddy hosted site?

Tags: web-hosting, https

I've got a GoDaddy hosted site which currently has a long expired SSL certificate on it.  The site is a simple static site with no data.  However, since it's an outward facing site it falls under compliance regulations which require it to either have current and working SSL or not at all.  I would like to just shut down the SSL as there's no point in paying money to have SSL on a site which does not need it.  So far I've been unable to figure out how to do anything with SSL on it's control panel though.

Is it possible to turn off SSL for it completely?  If so, how?

Comment: I suggest calling GoDaddy tech support which has always been good to me. As well, there is certainly not enough information to answer this question. Please tell us more about your configuration/situation/scenario so that we are not left guessing.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch When you log into GoDaddy, under _My Account -> Products_ you should see "SSL". Click the "Options" button there and select the checkbox to cancel it. It will take a day to remove the SSL from your hosting account. You may also need to call the hosting department, or send them an email if it's still there (clear your browser cache when checking). Note that they will likely remove the static IP address associated with your hosting account, if you've linked to or made use of that in any way.

Comment: It's a "Deluxe Classic Hosting Windows" web server account.  There's no SSL under the My Account / Products page.  If I launch the web site control panel, there is an SSL option, but it just takes me back to the product page.  Also, this user account hosts several domains, I just want to remove SSL from the one.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch You'll need to contact the hosting department to request that the expired SSL certificate be removed. Normally that would occur after one expires, and you would just get an error in your browser when trying to connect to HTTPS.

Comment: Since this question was asked, the best answer has become, "Don't!!"

Answer (score 3):

Though it is an old query, but could not find any effective answer, so thought to pen it down.

Please go to your GoDaddy Cpanel. 
To reach cpanel you can login to GoDaddy--> My Account --> Hosting
--> Select the domain for which you want to remove SSL. Click on "Web Hosting with cPanel".

- Once in Cpanel page, scroll down to "Security" section --> Click on
  "SSL/TLS".
- In "SSL/TLS" page, click on "Delete Private Keys (KEY)". Delete all your private keys.
- Then click on "delete SSL certificates." and delete expired certificate there.

You are done. It may take 1 hour to take effect.
Delete your browser cache and history, as Browser will keep redirecting to https site.

Extra Steps required if you have Wordpress or any other CMS driven portals. If You have Wordpress then from your Cpanel  click on "phpMyAdmin"

- Go to your Wordpress schema and click on WP-Options table.
- Change home and site URL to http from https.

[image]

For other CMS, Home URL and site URL need to be changed from respective table.

Answer (score 1):

[dan](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan) says:

When you log into GoDaddy, under My Account -> Products you should see "SSL". Click the "Options" button there and select the checkbox to cancel it. It will take a day to remove the SSL from your hosting account. You may also need to call the hosting department, or send them an email if it's still there (clear your browser cache when checking). Note that they will likely remove the static IP address associated with your hosting account, if you've linked to or made use of that in any way.

You'll need to contact the hosting department to request that the expired SSL certificate be removed. Normally that would occur after one expires, and you would just get an error in your browser when trying to connect to HTTPS.